# Nuget does not recognize assemblyinfo.cs version any longer

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, version

We have a DLL which we pack into a nuget package. The DLL's assemblyinfo.cs
includes this entries:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.*")]
```

After using following nuget command:

```
nuget pack dllproject.csproj -Symbols
```

we get a nuget package named as this:

```
dllproject.1.0.1215.16457.nupkg
```

This works on the machines of my coleagues and mine, furthermore on our build machine.

Now we had to switch to a new build machine. After setting up the system the nuget command everytime leads to following result:

```
dllproject.1.0.0.nupkg
```

It seems that something is missing and so autoincrement of the version does not work any more.

Have someone an idea what can i do that this will work again?

EDIT:
I found out that this only does not work in virtualized environments like Virtual machine or Proxmox/KVM. Does anybody knows why?

Comment: `[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]` uses a timestamp to fill in the last two fields. I don't know why that broke, but I'd rather go with something like `gitversion` to create the version info.

Answer (score 1):

Root cause for the problem was a bug in nuget.exe 5.9.1
After setting verbosity to detailed i can see an error while
trying to read assembly infos.
Using an older version of nuget.exe like 4.7.3 solved the problem.
Everything works as expected.